# Change UI State in netbeans. Does Netbeans have a state window concept for Java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, state

I am creating a UI application which has multiple UI states.
I was wondering if I could manage states using netbeans functionality.

I had used flex before and they do have a way of managing states. A State Window.
Does Netbeans have similar functionality?

If not how do we go about maintaining states and previewing them in the design window?

Comment: What do you mean by `state window`?

Comment: A UI state is a different View. If i click one button I would like to change View. Have a look at http://netbeans.org/kb/69/javafx/parallel-states.html#create-project

Comment: Are you looking for [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)?

Comment: Not exactly. Its like if i click a button a new View will be displayed. So manually you would set the current widgets. setVisible(false) and allow other UI widgets to show up on the screen.

Comment: Are you building an application based on the NetBeans **Platform** or a standard Swing application?